# 3D model file searching for Sony QX1

Tags: sony, camera-design

I am looking for Sony QX1 3D model file. Because I want to add the integrated circuit on QX1. Actually I don't known that this question to ask in here. Sorry if I have mistake. Sorry my language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's probably not photography related. You should probably ask SE.Electronics

Comment: @Olivier Could we please refrain form sending people to other sites on hunches. In this case there is literally no stackexchange site that would accept this. Theres no 3D modelling site, and Engineering does not allow offsite resources questions of this kind. Its not a attack on you Osman, just a artefact of the larger problem at hand.

Comment: Sometimes questions are off topic and there just isn't a site for them. That doesn't make them more on topic. However, in this case it seems like it might be a DIY camera hacking question, which might be on topic. Osman, can you explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Welcome to [photo.se]! I'm **not** voting to close this because I think it is on topic. We have plenty of questions regarding technical details of photography equipment like card write speeds, flash voltages, thread sizes, etc. This question belongs in the same category.

Comment: Don't you love [how Sony sends people to stackoverflow](https://developer.sony.com/support/stack-overflow/)? But, AFAIK, they've only opened up a software API for the QX1, **not** the hardware. Not sure what the OP wants (board schematics?) is to be had. At least, not without a contract and signing an NDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find 3D model here: [sony-qx1-1](https://grabcad.com/library/sony-qx1-1) or here: [sony-qx1l-modeling-by-nx-9-0-1](https://grabcad.com/library/sony-qx1l-modeling-by-nx-9-0-1)
Hope this helps :)